# Unable to run django test in CircleCI

Tags: python, django, circleci, circleci-2.0

I am implementing CircleCI for one of the projects. The project is built on Django 3.2.

My test cases run properly when I run using `python manage.py test blog`, when I run the same in CircleCI it returns ,

```
======================================================================
ERROR: project.blog (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: project.blog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 470, in _find_test_path
    package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project.blog'
```

Here is my CircleCI config

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.8
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Installing dependencies
          command: |
            python3 -m venv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            pip3 install -r requirements.txt
      - run:
          name: Running migrations
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            python manage.py migrate --skip-checks
      - run:
          name: Running tests
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            python manage.py test blog
```

I understand that CircelCI clones the project in project folder. Is that something that I am missing in config?

Answer (score 0):

CircleCI by default checkouts our codebase to `/home/circleci/project`, problem was in list of installed_apps I had an app with name `project`.(which was conflicting)

**When CircleCI ran `python manage.py test` the `unittest` module was searching the app `blog` inside django app `project`.**

I fixed this problem by changing the default path to which CircleCI puts out codebase. Here is the updated CircleCI config

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/platform #Here is the answer
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.8
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/platform #Here is the answer
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            ls -l
            python3 -m venv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            pip3 install -r requirements.txt
      - run:
          name: Run migrations
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            python manage.py migrate --skip-checks
      - run:
          name: Run tests
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            python manage.py test website
```